# Binding multiple ExternalNames into one service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Ok, so pretty straightforward. I have the same service running on different (independent) clusters (and/or VMs). Is there a way to have this combined at my other cluster?

Something like this maybe?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: some-service
  namespace: some-service
  annotations:
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalName: host1.bla.local, host2.bla.local, host3.bla.local, ...
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

Is there a better way to combine ExternalName services?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: Kubernetes is v1.23.5 on a "bare metal installation" running on Linux VMs on "local"/intranet VMs.